# Delete TFSGit Stale Branches on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, branch, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I've been looking to find a way to delete any old (stale) branches in Azure Devops (TFSGit) with an API instead of the tedious method of 1 by 1.

The only API reference I could find to show me the branches is this one ([List Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)). However, if basically gives the name and ID but nothing else like last date modified etc.

Neither of these work or return information [List Branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source%20providers/list%20branches?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or [Get Branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches/get%20branches?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

I'm looking to utilise an API to delete branches in our TFSGit repository for branches older than x days that are not locked.

Anybody able to assist?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

At present, we do not have the api to get the branch last modified time. So, it looks we can not use an API to delete branches in our TFSGit repository for branches older than x days that are not locked.